# Reading a value from a session variable into a local variable in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I really hope you can help me.
I usually read my session variables into a local variable, so that I don't have to create endless read locks.
But I came across some interesting behavior. Note that I have not applied any write locks for brevity's sake:

Consider the following:

---

EXAMPLE 1:

```
<cfset session.testvalue = 1 />
<cfset lcktestvalue = session.testvalue />
<cfoutput>#lcktestvalue#</cfoutput><br />
<cfset session.testvalue = 2 />
<cfoutput>#lcktestvalue#</cfoutput>
```

OUTPUT:

1
1

---

EXAMPLE 2:

```
<cfset session.testvalue1.item = 1 />
<cfset lcktestvalue1 = session.testvalue1 />
<cfoutput>#lcktestvalue1.item#</cfoutput><br />
<cfset session.testvalue1.item = 2 />
<cfoutput>#lcktestvalue1.item#</cfoutput>
```

OUTPUT:

1
2

---

I am trying to work out why the second example, updates the 'lcktestvalue1.item', when the value was only read once?
I would have expected example 1 & 2 to produce the same output, and the following to produce the second example's output:

---

EXAMPLE 3:

```
<cfset session.testvalue1.item = 1 />
<cfset lcktestvalue1 = session.testvalue1 />
<cfoutput>#lcktestvalue1.item#</cfoutput><br />
<cfset session.testvalue1.item = 2 />
<cfset lcktestvalue1 = session.testvalue1 />
<cfoutput>#lcktestvalue1.item#</cfoutput>
```

OUTPUT:

1
2

---

The only reason for this behavior, I can think of, is that the second example, uses a structure inside a structure.
But,I cannot expand on this concept. Can you?
I really need to understand this, because I am creating a shopping cart, which makes extensive use of the methodology in example 2. It actually works fine, but I am not sure why, and I am afraid under load, it may fail?

Thank you for any help you can give me on this.

Comment: "Endless read locks"? What version of CF are you using? Unless you're dealing with some funky race conditions you probably don't need to lock session variables at all.

Comment: Better to be safe than sorry. I have heard quite a few scare stories about session race condition, even with CF10. From what I have read, there are a couple of bugs, which means that this issue still has not been fully addressed by Adobe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Charles, This is is expected behavior. Structures and objects are passed *by reference* - meaning you are actually just setting a pointer to a memory location to get at the underlying object. When the set statement is dealing with a *primitive* (a string, number, date etc) it *copies* the data into your new variable - so this:

```
<Cfset session.testvalue = 1/>
<cfset testvalue = session.testvalue/>
```

...actually creates 2 locations each containing a "1"

When you are dealing with an object however (a structure, component, function, query etc. - anything *not primitive*), like this:

```
<cfset session.testvalue.item1 = 1/>
<cfset testvalue = session.testvalue/>
```

The *variables.testvalue* variable is actually a pointer to the *structure* you created in the set statement (session.testvalue.item1 implicitely creates a structure).

This is important fundamental stuff - especially when dealing with CFCs, functions, application scopes etc. This post on [Primitive vs complex variables](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2009/3/17/primitive.vs.complex) explains it in more detail.

It has nothing to do with locking by the way. Unless you have some demonstratable race condition you need not go overbord with locking.

I would note that your practice here is probably not a great idea - you should probably be scoping your local vars as *variables.varName* any way in which case pushing session variables to that scope is not saving you any effort.

NOTE: While I was writing this Ray chimed in with a short concise answer exactly to the point (while I was being verbose).

NOTE 2: In ColdFusion there is one nuance that some find unexpected - arrays are passed by value (as a copy) and *not* by reference. This can throw you sometimes - and if you ever do an array of objects

Comment: Sorry Ray, I made sure and noted that you were first to answer this.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Great explanation. Can I infer that my SESSION values are still safe. Presumably the pointer has a hidden sessionid, as well, which differentiates between many different users' sessions?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking - but if you mean safe as in tied to the user then us. There is a sessionID (which can take a couple of forms in CF) that is tied to a cookie. In your specific example you can screw up data _per user_ but not accross users. For that you would need to use the same approach with Application variables :D

Comment: Just one little question. Are you sure I need to prefix local variables, when there are just local & session scopes being used in a CF template. I understand, that this is good practice when there are 'url' & 'form' variables flying around. Although, in certain cases, it is advantageous not to differentiate between 'local', 'form' & 'url', if you want to implement a first come, first read system.

Comment: "In your specific example you can screw up data per user but not accross users". How would it be possible to screw up data per user? Sorry, I am not clear on this?

Comment: Because you are passing references around you can inadvertently change the value of the underlying session variable by altering your local reference to it - exactly as in your example. Doing it this way (passing around references from scope to scope) makes your code more complex and introduces vectors for unexpected errors.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Actually, I only ever read from the local reference. I never write to it, because I actually never thought it would write to the session simultaneously. Wow, I have really learnt an important lesson today...

Answer (score 9):

Because your second example is making a pointer, or a reference, from the original value to the new value. You can think of it is an imaginary string between the two such that when one is changed - the other is as well. This happens with structures. You can get around this by using duplicate.

But NOTE! The need to obsessively cflock session/app/server variables has NOT been necessary for nearly ten years. You still have to worry about race conditions, but for 99% of the time this is not your concern.

Comment: Ray. Thanks for this very concise & visually appealing answer. I like the string idea. I used to read session values into a local variable, so that I could avoid numerous read locks, but I guess old habits die hard!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Duplicate() if you want to copy/clone the structure and not just make a reference to the object stored in SESSION.

```
    <cfset session.testvalue1.item = 1 />
    <cfset lcktestvalue1 = Duplicate(session.testvalue1) />
    <cfoutput>#lcktestvalue1.item#</cfoutput><br />
    <cfset session.testvalue1.item = 2 />
    <cfoutput>#lcktestvalue1.item#</cfoutput>
```

Output

```
    1
    1
```

[Coldfusion WikiDocs](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Duplicate)